# Pandas to_sql if_exist does not work

Tags: sql, pandas, file-upload

I am trying to upload Pandas dataframe to Teradata SQL database. I can only upload the dataframe successfully if the table does not exist. If exists, I cannot replace or append to the table using the if_exists option of to_sql. Please help.

```
import teradata
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import keyring

user = 'XXX'
pwd = keyring.get_password("TDATA", "XXX")
host = '0.0.0.0'
create_engine('teradata://'+ user +':' + pwd + '@'+ host + ':22/', echo=False)
#df is a pandas dataframe, dtypes is a dictionary specifying data types
df.to_sql(name='table', schema='db', con=td_engine, if_exists='append', dtype=dtypes)
```

sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (teradata.api.DatabaseError) (3803, u"[42S01] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Table 'table' already exists.